# ExpressJS routing errors

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a collection of microservices. The problem is, my routes don't seem to redirect to the right place.

Here is my index.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var timestamp = require("./routes/timestamp");

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.end("Hi! This is a collection of microservices. <a href='https://github.com/Humad/timestamp-microservice'>See instructions here.</a>");
});

app.get("/timestamp", timestamp);
```

And here is my 'timestamp' file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require("moment");

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello world!");
});

router.get("/:date", function(req, res){
    var newDate = req.params.date;

    var natural = moment.utc(newDate, "MMMM D, YYYY", true);
    var unix = moment.utc(newDate, "X", true);

    if (natural.isValid() || unix.isValid()) {
        if (natural.isValid()) {
            newDate = natural;
        } else {
            newDate = unix;
        }

        res.json({unix: newDate.format("X"), natural: newDate.format("MMMM D, YYYY")});
    } else {
        res.json({unix: null, natural: null});
    }

    res.end();    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is whats SUPPOSED to happen:

localhost/timestamp should give me "Hello World!"
localhost/timestamp/someDate should give me a JSON file with the dates

But here is what actually happens:

localhost/timestamp gives me a JSON file with the dates
localhost/timestamp/someDate gives me a Cannot GET error
And the "Hello World" is never shown

Comment: shouldnt localhost/timestamp throw an error since youre not providing the date parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line `app.get("/timestamp", timestamp);` to `app.use("/timestamp", timestamp);`.

I think you intended mounting the timestamp Router **middleware** on `/timestamp` path, and not as a callback to a GET request which is what you are currently doing.